# Obfuscation in IBM Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

Although I understand that the chances are very minimal in cracking an application which is distributed via Appstore, I still want to obfuscate my worklight project for security reasons. Is there any inbuilt tool available within Worklight Studio or if not any plugin which can meet my requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obfuscation is not a bullet-proof security measure. Anyway, Worklight does not provide this ability built-in, however you can follow the instructions from this IBM Worklight blog post, about obfuscating your application's JavaScript code:

- [Obfuscating JavaScript code in Worklight applications](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/obfuscating_javascript_code?lang=en)

From the blog post:

> It is very important to understand that code obfuscation, especially in
>   JavaScript, is a relatively weak security measure. Most modern web
>   debugging tools are smart enough to "prettify" the obfuscated code
>   reverting it to a much more readable (however still not original)
>   format.

Comment: Agreed Idan, However the idea is to uglify the code and deliver one additional layer of security instead of directly passing the prettified code. Do you have any best practice ideas other than obfuscation which can secure Javascript Files and should this be extended to the adpter front as well ?